# Optimizing MongoDB aggregation queries

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new to Mongo, I was able to create a query that gives the output I require. But it came out very long (for what seems like a simple query).

Tips on how to optimize it would be welcome.

To summarize, I have 5 items and the query should get the info of the **last modified item** and the **last modified project** of that item + **names of other projects that item has**. It also needs to retrieve the **names and id's of all other items**.

This is a sample of one item (all are similar like this):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a16ebc6871fbc64c0e39e43"),
"date_modified" : ISODate("2017-12-15T07:18:04.774Z"),
"name" : "TEST COMPANY 1",
"projects" : [ 
    {
        "project" : {
            "name" : "TEST PROJECT 1",
            "date_modified" : ISODate("2014-12-15T07:18:04.774Z"),
            "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu pharetra nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate commodo lectus, ac blandit elit tincidunt id. Sed rhoncus, tortor sed eleifend tristique, tortor mauris molestie elit, et lacinia ipsum quam nec dui. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Vivamus varius pretium ligula, a aliquam odio euismod sit amet. Quisque laoreet sem sit amet orci ullamcorper at ultricies metus viverra. Pellentesque arcu mauris, malesuada quis ornare accumsan, blandit sed diam.",
            "url" : "test_project_1",
            "task_groups" : [ 
                {
                    "task_group" : {
                        "id" : "1",
                        "folders" : [ 
                            {
                                "folder" : {
                                    "name" : "test folder 1",
                                    "tasks" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "task" : {
                                                "name" : "test task 1",
                                                "versions" : [ 
                                                    {
                                                        "version" : {
                                                            "id" : "1"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "tasks" : [ 
                            {
                                "task" : {
                                    "name" : "test task 1",
                                    "versions" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "version" : {
                                                "id" : "1"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "project" : {
            "name" : "TEST PROJECT 2",
            "date_modified" : ISODate("2017-12-15T07:18:04.774Z"),
            "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu pharetra nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate commodo lectus, ac blandit elit tincidunt id. Sed rhoncus, tortor sed eleifend tristique, tortor mauris molestie elit, et lacinia ipsum quam nec dui. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Vivamus varius pretium ligula, a aliquam odio euismod sit amet. Quisque laoreet sem sit amet orci ullamcorper at ultricies metus viverra. Pellentesque arcu mauris, malesuada quis ornare accumsan, blandit sed diam.",
            "url" : "test_project_1",
            "task_groups" : [ 
                {
                    "task_group" : {
                        "id" : "1",
                        "folders" : [ 
                            {
                                "folder" : {
                                    "name" : "test folder 1",
                                    "tasks" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "task" : {
                                                "name" : "test task 1",
                                                "versions" : [ 
                                                    {
                                                        "version" : {
                                                            "id" : "1"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "tasks" : [ 
                            {
                                "task" : {
                                    "name" : "test task 1",
                                    "versions" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "version" : {
                                                "id" : "1"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

This is my query, like I said, it does the work, but I'm not sure how well I have used the options Mongo's aggregation has:

```
const searchQuery = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {
            "date_modified": -1,
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "firstPipe": { "$first": { "name": "$name", "id": "$_id", "date_modified": "$date_modified", "projects": "$projects" } },
            "otherCompanies": { "$push": { "name": "$name", "id": "$_id" } },
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$firstPipe.projects" },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "firstPipe.projects.project.date_modified": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "firstProject": { "$first": "$firstPipe.projects" },
            "projectNames": { "$push": { "project": { "name": "$firstPipe.projects.project.name" } } },
            "secondPipe": { "$first": { "name": "$firstPipe.name", "id": "$firstPipe.id", "date_modified": "$firstPipe.date_modified" } },
            "otherCompanies": { "$first": "$otherCompanies" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "projects": { "$concatArrays": [["$firstProject"], { "$slice": ["$projectNames", 1, { "$size": "$projectNames" }] }] },
            "secondPipe": "$secondPipe",
            "otherCompanies": "$otherCompanies"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "thirdPipe": { "$push": { "name": "$secondPipe.name", "id": "$secondPipe.id", "date_modified": "$secondPipe.date_modified", "projects": "$projects" } },
            "otherCompanies": { "$first": "$otherCompanies" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "data": { "$concatArrays": ["$thirdPipe", { "$slice": ["$otherCompanies", 2, { "$size": "$otherCompanies" }] }] }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$data" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } },
]);
```

This is the output I get and require:

```
[
  {
    "name": "TEST COMPANY 1",
    "id": "5a16ebc6871fbc64c0e39e43",
    "date_modified": "2017-12-15T07:18:04.774Z",
    "projects": [
      {
        "project": {
          "name": "TEST PROJECT 2",
          "date_modified": "2017-12-15T07:18:04.774Z",
          "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu pharetra nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate commodo lectus, ac blandit elit tincidunt id. Sed rhoncus, tortor sed eleifend tristique, tortor mauris molestie elit, et lacinia ipsum quam nec dui. Quisque nec mauris sit amet elit iaculis pretium sit amet quis magna. Aenean velit odio, elementum in tempus ut, vehicula eu diam. Pellentesque rhoncus aliquam mattis. Ut vulputate eros sed felis sodales nec vulputate justo hendrerit. Vivamus varius pretium ligula, a aliquam odio euismod sit amet. Quisque laoreet sem sit amet orci ullamcorper at ultricies metus viverra. Pellentesque arcu mauris, malesuada quis ornare accumsan, blandit sed diam.",
          "url": "test_project_1",
          "task_groups": [
            {
              "task_group": {
                "id": "1",
                "folders": [
                  {
                    "folder": {
                      "name": "test folder 1",
                      "tasks": [
                        {
                          "task": {
                            "name": "test task 1",
                            "versions": [
                              {
                                "version": {
                                  "id": "1"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "tasks": [
                  {
                    "task": {
                      "name": "test task 1",
                      "versions": [
                        {
                          "version": {
                            "id": "1"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "project": {
          "name": "TEST PROJECT 1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST COMPANY 4",
    "id": "5a16ebc6871f1c64c0e39e41"
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST COMPANY 3",
    "id": "5a16ebc6871fbc64c0e39e11"
  },
  {
    "name": "TEST COMPANY 2",
    "id": "5a16ebc6871fbc64c0e39e41"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify little bit by moving the logic to separate the projects.

Couple of changes

[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) now takes care of splitting the projects by locating the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) modified date with [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to return the whole project doc when the max date modified matches the project element else return name.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage to embed the projects back into main document.

```
[
  {"$sort":{"date_modified":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":0,
    "topdata":{"$first":{"name":"$name","id":"$_id","date_modified":"$date_modified"}},
    "projects":{
      "$first":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{"ldm":{"$max":"$projects.project.date_modified"}},
          "in":{
            "$map":{
              "input":"$projects",
              "as":"project",
              "in":{
                "$cond":{
                  "if":{"$eq":["$$project.project.date_modified","$$ldm"]},
                  "then":"$$project",
                  "else":{"project":{"name":"$$project.project.name"}}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "otherCompanies":{"$push":{"name":"$name","id":"$_id"}}
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$projects"},
  {"$sort":{"projects.project.date_modified":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":0,
    "topdata":{"$first":"$topdata"},
    "projects":{"$push":"$projects"},
    "otherCompanies":{"$first":"$otherCompanies"}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"topdata.projects":"$projects"}},
  {"$project":{"data":{"$concatArrays":[["$topdata"],{"$slice":["$otherCompanies",1,{"$size":"$otherCompanies"}]}]}}},
  {"$unwind":"$data"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
]
```